# Metric tensor via inclusion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, pullback

> Consider the Riemannian manifold $(\mathrm S^3_+, i^*g)$, where $i : \rm S^3 \rightarrow\Bbb R^4$ is the inclusion, $g = g_{\Bbb R^4}$ is the euclidean metric and $\rm S^3_+ = \{ (x,y,z,t)^T : t >0\}$. We denote $\tilde g = i^*g$, analytically determine the coefficients $\tilde g_{i,j}$, $i,j = 1,2,3$.

I was thinking that since $\rm S^3 \subset \Bbb R^4$ the inclusion act as the identity and pullback of identity is also identity, so could I say that the coefficients are exactly the same of the standard euclidean metric? Otherwise I'm not really sure how to proceed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Without a local coordinates on $\mathbb S^3_+$, it is unclear which $\tilde g_{ij}$ are you referring to.

Comment: @ArcticChar on the exercises isn't specified which local coordinates are on $\Bbb S^3_+$, if we suppose to have stereographic projections?

Comment: Since it is the upper hemisphere might be they want you to use the graph $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, z, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2-z^2})$. But it could be any chart I suppose.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ok, with these global graph coordinates (since the upper hemisphere could be covered by a single chart) the point now is working out the pullback of the map that you describe. At this point my previous reasoning is wrong because even though inclusion act like identity, I have to consider locally in which chart I'm in, in order to find $\tilde{g}_{i,j}$, am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes exactly. Indeed $g_{ij}$ would never be the identity map, since the curvature of $\mathbb S^3_+$ is not zero.